# Unityのエラー

Tags: unity3d

Unity公式サイトで「はじめてのUnity」で勉強し始めたものです。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DangerWall : MonoBehaviour {
    //オブジェクトと接触した時に呼ばれるコールバック 
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision hit)
    {
        //もし接触したオブジェクトのタグが”Player”の場合 
        if(hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")){

            //現在のシーン番号を取得 
            int sceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
        } 
    }



}
```

エラーが出るのは

```
int sceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex; 

SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
```

の部分で
「SceneManagerはこのコンテキストに存在しない」
というエラーが出ます。
どこの部分に問題があるのか教えてください！

Answer (score 4):

[障害物とリスタート→シーンの再読込](https://unity3d.com/jp/learn/tutorials/projects/hajiuni/adding-obstacles-and-restart)のコードと比較するとusingが足りないようです。
これがエラーの原因ではないでしょうか。

**リンク先のusing**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

が必要です。